# Python file search program not fast enough

Tags: python, file-search

I wrote the following code for searching a file on your computer:

```
import os, sys
import win32api

x=raw_input("Enter file name: ")

drives = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings()
drives = drives.split('\000')[:-1]
for drive in drives:
    for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(drive):
        for filename in filenames:
            if x.upper() in filename:
                print"FILE FOUND!"
                print('FILE INSIDE ' + folderName + ': '+ filename)
            elif x.lower() in filename:
                print"FILE FOUND!"
                print('FILE INSIDE ' + folderName + ': '+ filename)
            elif x.capitalize() in filename:
                print"FILE FOUND!"
                print('FILE INSIDE ' + folderName +': '+ filename)
a=raw_input("Press any key to exit.")
sys.exit()
```

As you may have noticed this program is not fast enough.

So could anyone help me make a faster and more efficient version of this program?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "fast enough"? How fast would you like it to be compared to what it is now? Hard drive access in general is very slow. `os.walk()` was also updated in Python 3.5 to be much faster, so if you're using Python 2 that might contribute to it.

Comment: It won't change much in terms of speed but to just noting that your `if`s are mutually exclusive so you can make two of 'em `elif`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't enhance this program much - any static file search will have to do that sort of thing. By adding a lot of complexity and making it parallel, you could get it to work faster by walking different portions of the file system at a time, and possibly enabling a "lucky hit" earlier.

Applications and utilities that are designed for fast search of the file system usually resort to indexing all file system contents in a database - and they keep doing that either continuously on the background, or at a fixed time of the day. So, when there is a a search,they just perform a query on that database.

This solution however would increase the complexity of your small program several times - and it would be too complex to write here as  an answer;

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But, could you tell me more about your idea in the first paragraph with an example? I find it interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Reducing the number of print statements should increase speed significantly. If you need to trace the files, you could write your results to a log file instead.